# Where can I find the oracle10g database related files to my netbeans project?

Tags: oracle10g, netbeans-6.9

I have made a College Management System project in Java using Netbeans 6.9.1 and Oracle10g. where can I find the database files related to my project so that i can export those files to another system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "database files" you mean your tables, procedures and other data, then they are contained in Oracle's [data files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm).

You'll have to [export the data and then import them on another system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671705/is-this-the-right-way-to-import-oracle-dump-database).